# how to create an icon button in X11?

Tags: ubuntu, x11, c++

I am using `x11` library for creating a simple window application in Linux. I want to add an icon button (graphical button) to my app - something similar to this: [image: customised icon]

Are there any instructions on how to create this button on `Xlib/X11`?

Answer (score 1):

libX11 is too low level for that - you need a higher level toolkit library (such as GTK or Qt) to implement buttons and icons, and the toolkit translates that into libX11 calls to draw images and monitor regions for button press events.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible! write image as a image.xpm (can use Gimp), and `#include <xpm.h>` as well as `#include "image.xpm"`